# When to use .flatMap() on a Mono instead of just calling a function on a value?

Tags: java, spring, reactive-programming, project-reactor, reactor

I'm looking at some code where .flatMap was called on a Mono - I've gone through some of the PR discussions on Rx GitHubs about adding such functionality, but I don't really understand why someone would do that: flatMap, to me, seems inherently purposed for applying a function to 1...n elements. Applying a function to 0...1 elements can be done with a single function call.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.map()` as long as it is non-blocking.

Otherwise, your inner transformation will return `Mono` that will complete in future (e.g. a network call), and you should subscribe on it with `.flatMap` instead of blocking the processing.

`flatMap` works with any `Publisher<T>` and works with any `0..n` where `n` can also be `0`.

If you need to transform one element into a few (e.g. split a String) then you can use `flatMapIterable`, it has lower overhead than `flatMap`.

Comment: In code that's largely imperative, is there any reason to be using Monos an flatMap in lieu of completableFutures and standard function calls? It seems like the code I'm looking at could just be doing that instead.